Is Lightning message channel supported by popstate event in LWC? unable to get the message when user click browser back button
Publish component:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import submitCaseTAPoc from '@salesforce/messageChannel/submitCaseTAPoc__c';
export default class Publisher extends LightningElement {
@wire(MessageContext) messageContext;

connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', this.handlePopState.bind(this));
                      }
     handlePopState(event) {
    if (event.state) {
       
        try {
                const message = { data: 'Hello from Publisher' };
                publish(this.messageContext, submitCaseTAPoc, message);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during messagechannel:', error);
        }*/
        console.log('After the messagechannel');      }    
}

subscriber component:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import submitCaseTAPoc from '@salesforce/messageChannel/submitCaseTAPoc__c';
 
export default class Subscriber extends LightningElement {
    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;
 
    connectedCallback() {
        subscribe(this.messageContext, submitCaseTAPoc, (message) => {
            console.log(message.data); // Output: Hello from Publisher
        });
    }
}

It is showing [error: invalid message context]

I've just done a quick test, with two LWCs arranged in the Lightning App Builder side by side, and for me it worked. It's not clear from your text, where you get this error message. Is this during execution of "@wire(MessageContext) messageContext;" (on returning to the page)?
